# Devise and Factory Girl: Mysql2::Error: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `auth_user`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a valid `auth_user` with FactoryGirl, my factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :auth_user, class: AuthUser do
    username 'Test'
    first_name 'Wilson'
    last_name 'Mandela'
    email 'test@test.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    is_staff true
    is_active true
    is_superuser true
    last_login DateTime.now
    date_joined DateTime.now
  end    
end
```

When I try to create an `auth_user` in Rspec like this: `auth_user = create(:auth_user)`

then I receive the following error:

Mysql2::Error: Field 'password' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `auth_user`

It seems Devise doesn't accept the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields in the Factory. What can I do to still create a test `auth_user`? I couldn't find any help on the Devise Wiki but I may have overlooked it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving suggests that you have a field in your database table called `password`. This is going to create problems for you because it will conflict with Devise's virtual attribute by the same name.

The field in your DB should be called `encrypted_password`, which is what should have been created when you ran `rails generate devise auth_user`.  If that's not the case, or if you added another field called `password`, fix the migration and then run `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20150...etc-for-that-migration`.